# Can I use Veritias Storage Manager to provide HA storage using server-local storage?

Tags: redhat, filesystems, high-availability

I have a need to provide an high-availability ftp/http file repository. Upload will happne to one server, but the uploaded file must be immediately visisble on all other servers

I can handle the failover of the servers themeselves using load balancers. But in the event of failure of one server, the other servers must see the same contents of the repository. Normally, I'd use a SAN for this, but in this case the data centre standards do not allow SAN/external storage - all storage will be local to the servers.

Cam I use Veritas Storage Manager (or any other product) to manage mirroring hte contents between servers in this way? Or does that require a SAN? I couldn't tell either way from a quick look at the data sheets etc.

Comment: Define "immediately". The way you describe your environment it sounds like a active/passive-cluster. So no need for real time in normal circumstances? How far away are the other servers?

Comment: Immediately means the uploaded file may be used (by some other device) as soon as the ftp upload session is closed (one app uploads the file, and when the upload is complete, immediately instructs another device to download it).

Comment: So "immediately" is - in near time after a file has been uploaded.

Comment: Now second part of the question: How far away are your other servers? Internet or internal network?

Comment: Servers are all co-located. And immediately isn't really in near time, it's arbitairily close to when the file has completed uploading

Comment: ok - do have a specific operating system? Solaris/Linux/something else?

Comment: Linux (RH). Although if pushed, we could do Solaris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using colocated redhat systems you can use a number of solutions.

First of all - yes Veritas Volume manager can do this - you can set it up to replicate to a remote volume. It has been a while ago that I have been using this feature as integrated solution for a remote HA-NFS solution using Veritas Filesystem, Volume Manager, Cluster and Global Cluster.

I think that replication feature is now built into the standard volume-manager, but I am not sure if you need an additional licence.

With RedHat you can use a number of additional alternatives:

- DRBD (8.3 or higher)
- iSCSI with RAID 1 via `mdadm`
- triggering an action after upload (like rsync to other servers) with [ionotify](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41929/what-is-the-concept-of-refresh-in-linux-if-there-is-so?lq=1) (in RH `gamin` seems to contain fam-libs)

The simplest solution will possibly to rig together `fam` and `rsync`.

To have the files really fast on other locations use one of the other solutions.

You will have to couple those with a cluster-aware-file-system.

If you already have a redhat-cluster up and running, you can use **GFS2**.

For anything else I can recommend **OCFS2**, which is part of Oracle-Linux (a binary compatible redhat-clone, so you can use the rpms).

Comment: Thanks. The question was rendered irrelevant as the data centre policies turned out to forbid shared file systems for solutions like the one we have, but this may well be useful in future